# Generate API and Data Model java files from Open API Generator

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I want to generate API and data model java files for my spring boot project through Open Api Generator (not Swagger code generator). http://api.openapi-generator.tech/index.html

This is the yaml file.

https://forge.3gpp.org/rep/sa5/MnS/raw/Rel-16/OpenAPI/provMnS.yaml

Note: yaml file has $ref in schema.

```
           schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/NotifyMoiCreation'
```

I have tried to create through open api online generator but not able to create it. I am giving the yml file in the box but it is stuck at loading. Please help.

[image]

Getting this error on dev tool console if I upload the yaml file url.

[image]

Getting this error on dev tool console if I upload the yaml file from my local machine and also all the other dependency yaml files are present in the same folder along with provMnS.yaml:

[image]

**Note :** The main provMnS.yaml file has dependency on other yaml files.

$ref: 'comDefs.yaml#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'  etc...

Comment: Open the browser dev tools > Console tab. Are there any errors? If yes, what does the error message say?

Comment: @Helen I have updated the Question with the snapshot where you can see the dev tools console.

Comment: Also the main file provMnS.yaml has dependency on other yaml files...
$ref: 'comDefs.yaml#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse' etc...